# Why to use Schedulers.single(customScheduler) when Flux is already sequential by default?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

**Code 1 with custom scheduler**

```
         Scheduler customScheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(
                    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
      
           
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .publishOn(customScheduler)      
        .subscribe(i -> {
               System.out.println("i is " + i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
               try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           });
```

**Code 2 with Scheduler.single(customScheduler)**

```
         Scheduler customScheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutor(
                    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    
         Scheduler single = Schedulers.single(customScheduler);
      
           
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .publishOn(single)      
        .subscribe(i -> {
               System.out.println("i is " + i + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
               try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           });
```

In both the code blocks, the output is same. As flux is sequential by default, what is the need of Schedulers.single()? How are the above two code blocks different in their functioning?

Answer (score 0):

From the fine manual:

```
Schedulers provides various Scheduler flavors usable by publishOn or subscribeOn :
    parallel(): Optimized for fast Runnable non-blocking executions
    single(): Optimized for low-latency Runnable one-off executions
    elastic(): Optimized for longer executions, an alternative for blocking tasks where the number of active tasks (and threads) can grow indefinitely
    boundedElastic(): Optimized for longer executions, an alternative for blocking tasks where the number of active tasks (and threads) is capped
    immediate(): to immediately run submitted Runnable instead of scheduling them (somewhat of a no-op or "null object" Scheduler)
    fromExecutorService(ExecutorService) to create new instances around Executors
```

So, I would say that a "one-off" execution is for when you want to put something on a thread and then return while it does its job. Parallel would be when you want to put something a several threads (the number of CPU cores for example) and return while each thread does its part. Ultimately, if you are going to put things on threads then you need to understand multithreading concepts.

Comment: What is the meaning of one-off execution here? Flux is a stream of elements. So, how can there be a one-off execution? Why can't we use parallel() scheduler in place of single()?

Comment: If that is the case, then why does Flux.interval() emit on parallel() scheduler? It should emit on single() scheduler.

Comment: Sounds like a separate question.

Comment: regarding schedulers.parallel(), unless we put .parallel() operator on a flux, it will anyways run sequentially even if we provide a parallel() scheduler. In my code block above, if we replace custom scheduler with parallel() scheduler, the output will be identical. Just the thread names will be different.